# Cannot access the function of jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to use ajax but it is not working when I clicks the button it does not show the alert box on browser.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ajax</title>
    <script scr="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    Name: <input type="text" id="data">
    <input type="submit" id="sub" value="save">

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#sub').click(function () {
                alert('ok');
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Theres a typo where you are calling the external JS. you have scr

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ajax</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#sub').click(function(){
                alert('ok');
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Name: <input type="text" id="data" >
        <input type="submit" id="sub" value="save">
    </body>
</html>
```

1. problem with the jquery path
2. always put the scripts in the head section

Comment: scripts does not have to be in the head section. in fact, it should be at the end for improved performance.

Comment: I agree but in this case if does not hinder the page performance so it is better to put it the head tag

Comment: Then why did you say **2. always put the scripts in the head section** ?